# Mailchimp API and Profile update email

Tags: mailchimp

The administration web interface of Mailchimp service let you edit a response email called "Profile email update".

When I update the profile of a member via API version 3.0, the member does not receive that email.

Since I'd rather not authenticate the members on my side, that email is critical.

Does anyone know if, by chance, there is a way to format the request to update the member so that Mailchimp sends the confirmation email and that the change will not be established immediately, but only after confirming the link in the email?

Actually, I call the endpoint `PATCH /lists/{list_id}/members/{id}` with a body like this:

```
{
  "interests" : {
    "<interest_id>" : <boolean>,
    "<interest_id>" : <boolean>,
    "<interest_id>" : <boolean>,
    "<interest_id>" : <boolean>
  }
}
```

I tried to add `"status" : "pending"`, but I just got the result to resend the subscription confirmation email, not the profile update one.

Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think "profile email update" does what you think it does. As far as I know, there's no way to make users verify that the changes to their profiles are legitimate. Typically what that's referring to is a link in an email to a page where the subscriber can update their profile if they want, not a confirmation of changes already made.

So the short answer is: no, that's not possible. When you make changes via the API (or the website) those changes take effect right away, without any confirmation by the subscriber.

Comment: You are definitely right! I will change my approach. Thank you.